# What is the difference between // and .// in XPath?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

When I execute these XPath expression on Chrome Developer Tools' console over google.com, I got the same results

- `$x("(.//*[@id='gs_lc0'])")`
- `$x("(//*[@id='gs_lc0'])")`

What is the usage of dot in XPath?

Comment: One **(//)** is an absolute path and the other **(.//)** is a relative path. The **(.//)** selects different nodesets per say in which the **(.)** means that it starts at the current node. On the other hand using **(//)** selects all element nodes with the attribute you supplied.

Comment: I don´t think so since an absolute path is build using /
something like
/html/body/h1

both are relative path

Comment: @PedroMachado: Has your question [**been answered**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39903294/290085) to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 3):

In XPath, `//` and `.//` are both syntactic abbreviations:

- `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`
- `.//` is short for `self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/`

The `descendant-or-self` axis contains the context node and all descendents of the context node.  **So the difference between `//` and `.//` reduces to a difference in context nodes.**

For `//`, the context node is the root node; `//` is an *[absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath)*.

For `.//`, the context node depends upon the context; `.//` is a [relative location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-RelativeLocationPath). At the top-level evaluation in Google Developer Tools console, the context node is the root node, so you'll see identical results.

**In short:**

- Use `//` when you wish to select nodes from the entire document.
- Use `.//` when you wish to select nodes only beneath the context node.