# XPath on subselection of an HTML page selecting extra elements?

Tags: python, html, xml, web-scraping, xpath

I am web-scraping a multipage directory with 100 table rows entries on each page.
I have downloaded the relevant pages and stored them as pickle files.
When trying to extract the information, I run into a weird problem that I do not understand:

I call XPath twice:

1. First to select the table rows. The result is stored in list. This works fine.
2. Second on the saved list of table rows. I would expect xpath to only check in that scope. However, what happens, is that xpath retrieves information from all table rows. An information that should not even be available to it at that point.

```
def information_extraction():
    website = store.unpickle_objects('test')
    utf8_parser = lxml.html.HTMLParser(encoding = "utf-8") # Handling encoding issues
    for page in website:
        page_content = lxml.html.fromstring(page, parser= utf8_parser)
        list = page_content.xpath('//table[contains(@id,"R1")]/tbody/tr')
        print ("Length list: ", len(list),", Type: ", type(list))# List with 100 table rows
        list_element = list[0]
        print (lxml.html.tostring(list_element)) # 1 row, correct html snippet
        first_link = list_element.xpath('//td[1]/a/@href')
        print(first_link) #Error, I get a list of all 100 occurrences from list and not the 1 contained in list_element
```

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Trying making your XPath relative by adding a leading period:  `.//td[1]/a/@href`

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes: An additional "." was all that was needed, the relative path works as expected. Now knowing what to search for, I found this [explanation](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2142-using-and-expressions-in-xpath-xml-search-directives-in-coldfusion.htm).

Comment: @Timoth04: Since that worked for you, I've added a full answer with explanation [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66698783/290085).

Answer (score 1):

Make your XPath relative to the context node by adding a leading period:

```
.//td[1]/a/@href
```

Without the leading period, the XPath is absolute, which means it uses the root node as the context and thereby searches the entire document.

See also [What is the difference between // and .// in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39902960/290085)